# What does Spark recover the data from a failed node?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, failover

Suppose we have an RDD, which is being used multiple times. So to save the computations again and again, we persisted this RDD using the rdd.persist() method.

So when we are persisting this RDD, the nodes computing the RDD will be storing their partitions.

So now suppose, the node containing this persisted partition of RDD fails, then what will happen? How will spark recover the lost data? Is there any replication mechanism? Or some other mechanism?

Comment: The same fault Torrance will work here only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do rdd.persist, rdd doesn't materialize the content. It does when you perform an action on the rdd. It follows the same lazy evaluation principle.

Now an RDD knows the partition on which it should operate and the DAG associated with it. With the DAG it is perfectly capable of recreating the materialized partition.

So, when a node fails the driver spawn another executor in some other node and provides it the Data partition on which it was supposed to work and the DAG associated with it in a closure. Now with this information it can recompute the data and materialize it.

In the mean time the cached data in the RDD won't have all the data in memory, the data of the lost nodes it has to fetch from the disk it will take so little more time.

On the replication, yes spark supports in memory replication. You need to set StorageLevel.MEMORY_DISK_2 when you persist.

```
rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_DISK_2)
```

This ensures the data is replicated twice.

Comment: I'd argue that _"Now an RDD knows the partition on which it should operate and the DAG associated with it. With the DAG it is perfectly capable of recreating the materialized partition."_ is correct. There's no RDD at runtime, but a set of tasks as a `TaskSet`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way I was able to understand how Spark is resilient was when someone told me that I should not think of RDDs as big, distributed arrays of data.

Instead I should picture them as a container that had instructions on what steps to take to convert data from data source and take one step at a time until a result was produced.

Now if you really care about losing data when persisting, then you can specify that you want to replicate your cached data.

For this, you need to select storage level. So instead of normally using this:

```
MEMORY_ONLY - Store RDD as deserialized Java objects in the JVM. If the RDD does not fit in memory, some partitions will not be cached and will be recomputed on the fly each time they're needed. This is the default level.
MEMORY_AND_DISK - Store RDD as deserialized Java objects in the JVM. If the RDD does not fit in memory, store the partitions that don't fit on disk, and read them from there when they're needed.
```

You can specify that you want your persisted data replcated

```
MEMORY_ONLY_2, MEMORY_AND_DISK_2, etc. -    Same as the levels above, but replicate each partition on two cluster nodes.
```

So if the node fails, you will not have to recompute the data.

Check storage levels here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence